# Bound on Tail of Riemann zeta function

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

I came across this bound in a lecture, and I don't know how to prove it or it's generalization.

> $$\sum_{k\geq n} \frac{1}{k^2}\leq \frac{c}{n}$$ for some constant $c$.

How do you prove the above? and how do you generalize this inequality for $0<p<2$ and
$$\sum_{k\geq n} \frac{1}{k^p}$$

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac1{k^2}$?

Comment: @SaucyO'Path You are both correct. This seems like a typo in the notes. I edited the question.

Comment: This is the bound from the integral test in calculus.  (Note your last series makes sense for $p > 1$, not for $p > 0$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First notice that $\frac{1}{k^2}\leqslant\int_{k-1}^k\frac{dx}{x^2}$, then for $n\geqslant 2$
$$ \sum_{k\geqslant n}\frac{1}{k^2}\leqslant\sum_{k\geqslant n}\int_{k-1}^k\frac{dx}{x^2}=\int_{n-1}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{1}{n-1}\leqslant\frac{2}{n} $$
You can do the same to get for $p>1$,
$$ \sum_{k\geqslant n}\frac{1}{k^p}\leqslant\frac{2^p}{n^p} $$